# How to extract the package name (substring) from AndroidManifest.xml in bash

Tags: android, bash

I want to extract the substring "com.example.alice" from

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"                                                                                           
android:versionCode="10" package="com.example.alice">
```

I was doing this:

```
ID=$(sed -n 's/package="\(.*\)/"\1/p' src/main/AndroidManifest.xml)
```

But it only works when the "package=" is in a separate line, like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.alice"
    android:versionCode="10003"
    android:versionName="1.0.3">
```

Answer (score 1):

Cyrus's suggestion works fine. You can also get the value with `grep` and a look-behind:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=package=)"[^"]*"' file
"com.example.alice"
```

That is, print everything that comes after `package=` and up to the next `"`.